# Problem in finding parameters for SIR model in R

Tags: r

I am trying to model the coronavirus infectious rate using SIR model in R. However, my beta (controls the transition between Susceptibles and Infected) and gamma (controls the transition between Infected and Recovered) values are not correct as you can see.

```
      beta     gamma 
 1.0000000 0.8407238
```

Here is my code:

```
library(deSolve)


Infected <- c(994, 307, 329, 553, 587, 843, 983, 1750, 2950, 4569, 5632, 4848, 9400, 10311, 11166, 13451, 17388, 18743, 19452, 20065, 20732,24914)
Day <- 1:(length(Infected))
N <- 331002651 # population of the us
```

This is the SIR function

```
SIR <- function(time, state, parameters) {
  par <- as.list(c(state, parameters))
  with(par, {
    dS <- -beta/N * I * S
    dI <- beta/N * I * S - gamma * I
    dR <- gamma * I
    list(c(dS, dI, dR))
  })
}
```

Then I find the RSS

```
init <- c(S = N-Infected[1], I = Infected[1], R = 0)
RSS <- function(parameters) {
  names(parameters) <- c("beta", "gamma")
  out <- ode(y = init, times = Day, func = SIR, parms = parameters)
  fit <- out[ , 3]
  sum((Infected - fit)^2)
}

Opt <- optim(c(0.5, 0.5), RSS, method = "L-BFGS-B", lower = c(0, 0), upper = c(1, 1)) # optimize with some sensible conditions
Opt$message
```

Then I find beta and gamma

```
Opt_par <- setNames(Opt$par, c("beta", "gamma"))
Opt_par
##      beta     gamma 
## 1.0000000 0.8407238
```

What went wrong with my code and how can I fix it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: My apology, I've added the init line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimization is often tricky, there are several things that may be improved:

- the model is very simple, you may consinder to use a SEIR model instead (being still to simple),
- extend the box constraints, this helped in your case,
- use another optimizer, e.g. from a meta-package like **FME**, that has also additional diagnostics,
- re-scale variables to a more convenient range, e.g. by dividing the population by 1e3,
- OR, as an alternative, adapt tolerances (`atol`) appropriate to the original scales.

```
library(deSolve)

Infected <- c(994, 307, 329, 553, 587, 843, 983, 1750, 2950, 4569, 5632, 4848, 
              9400, 10311, 11166, 13451, 17388, 18743, 19452, 20065, 20732,24914)
Day <- 1:(length(Infected))
N <- 331002651 # population of the us

SIR <- function(time, state, parameters) {
  par <- as.list(c(state, parameters))
  with(par, {
    dS <- -beta/N * I * S
    dI <- beta/N * I * S - gamma * I
    dR <- gamma * I
    list(c(dS, dI, dR))
  })
}

init <- c(S = N-Infected[1], I = Infected[1], R = 0)
RSS <- function(parameters) {
  names(parameters) <- c("beta", "gamma")
  out <- ode(y = init, times = Day, func = SIR, parms = parameters)
  fit <- out[ , 3]
  sum((Infected - fit)^2)
}

# optimize with some sensible conditions
Opt <- optim(c(0.5, 0.5), RSS, method = "L-BFGS-B", 
             lower = c(0, 0), upper = c(10, 10))
Opt$message

Opt_par <- setNames(Opt$par, c("beta", "gamma"))
Opt_par
# beta     gamma 
# 0.6512503 0.4920399 

out <- ode(y = init, times = Day, func = SIR, parms = Opt_par)

plot(out)
plot(out, obs=data.frame(time=Day, I=Infected))
```

A basic SEIR model and additional links can be found [here](https://github.com/tpetzoldt/covid). Note however that not only the model is too simple, but also the data. The number of confirmed cases is *not* the number of infected, it depends on how it was tested and is probably much less than the number of infected.