# How do I use my own dataset for the following simple SIR coding?

Tags: r

I want to incorporate my own dataset for this coding but I don't know at which part of the coding that I do that. Please help me. I've been trying to get the coding for MCMC SIR model for a long time. My dataset consist of the daily number of confirmed cases recovered cases and death cases. And if anyone has a better coding for this kind of problem please tell me. Thank you.

This is the coding (which is not mine):

```
library(deSolve)
sir = function(time, state, parameters){ ## this is the ODE system
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    dS = -beta * S * I
    dI = beta * S * I - gamma * I
    dR = gamma * I
    return(list(c(dS, dI, dR)))
  })
}

init = c(S = 1-1e-6, I = 1e-6, R = 0.0)
true.beta = 1.4247
true.gamma = 0.14286
parameters = c(beta = true.beta, gamma = true.gamma)
times = seq(0, 70, by = 1)
out = as.data.frame(ode(y = init, times = times, func = sir, parms = parameters))
out$time = NULL

true.sigma = 0.006
y_obs = rnorm(n = nrow(out), mean = out$I, sd = true.sigma) # data

matplot(times, out, type = "l", xlab = "Time", ylab = "Susceptibles and Recovered", 
        main = "SIR Model", lwd = 1, lty = 1, bty = "l", col = 2:4)
legend(40, 0.7, c("Susceptibles", "Infected", "Recovered"), pch = 1, col = 2:4)

### BEGIN MACHINERY
# par = an array containing (I[0], R[0], S[0], beta, gamma, sigma)
# In unconstrained space, we have transf(par) = c(log(beta), log(gamma), logit(I[0]), logit(R[0]), log(sigma))
# sigma = the standard deviation of the normal likelihood
# Note: here, they chose to include the initial conditions as part of the parameters to be estimated

## This function takes the parameter on an unconstrained scale and returns parameters to be estimated

getTransformedParameter = function(par) { 
  transfpar = rep(NA, length(par))
  unnorm = arm::invlogit(par[1:3])
  transfpar[1:3] = unnorm/sum(unnorm) ## Transform initial conditions
  transfpar[4:6] = exp(par[4:6])
  names(transfpar) = c("S", "I", "R", "beta", "gamma", "sigma")
  return(transfpar)
}

## This function takes the parameters and times and returns the solution to the ODEs
getSolution = function(par, times) { 
  allParameters = getTransformedParameter(par)
  sol = as.data.frame(ode(y = allParameters[1:3], times = time, func = sir, 
                          parms = allParameters[4:5]))
  return(sol$I)
}

Likelihood = function(par, times, data) {
  sol = getSolution(par, times)
  return(sum(dnorm(data, mean = sol, sd = exp(par[6]), log = TRUE)))
}

Prior = function(par) {
  tpars = getTransformedParameter(par)
  lpr = dbeta(tpars[1], 1, 1, log = TRUE) ## pi(S0)
  lpr <- lpr + dbeta(tpars[2], 1, 1, log = TRUE) ## pi(I0)
  lpr <- lpr + dbeta(tpars[3], 1, 1, log = TRUE) ## pi(R0)
  lpr <- lpr + dgamma(tpars[4], 1, 1, log = TRUE) ## pi(beta)
  lpr <- lpr + dgamma(tpars[5], 1, 1, log = TRUE) ## pi(gamma)
  lpr <- lpr + dgamma(tpars[6], .1, .1, log = TRUE) ## pi(sigma)
  return(lpr)
}

Target = function(pars, times, data) {
  return(Likelihood(pars, times = times, data = data) + Prior(pars))
}

### End Machinery

### Running the algorithm

library(adaptMCMC)
init.par = rnorm(6) # Initial guess for the parameters
chain = MCMC(p = Target, init = init.par, adapt = TRUE, acc.rate = 0.234, 
             n = 1E4, times = times, data = y_obs)

### Annotating results

Samples = chain$samples
for(i in 1:nrow(Samples)) {
  Samples[i,] = getTransformedParameter(chain$samples[I,])
}
burnin = 0.2
 Samples.bnin = Samples[round(burnin * nrow(Samples)): nrow(Samples),]

hist(Samples.bnin[, 4], xlab = expression(beta), main = "Posterior of infection rate")
abline(v = true.beta, lwd = 2, lty = 2)

hist(Samples.bnin[, 5], xlab = expression(gamma), main = "Posterior of recovery rate")
abline(v = true.gamma, lwd = 2, lty = 2)

hist(Samples.bnin[, 6], xlab = expression(sigma), main = "Posterior of likelihood standard 
deviation")
abline(v = true.sigma, lwd = 2, lty = 2)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Linked screenshots of code are not very helpful, because then the answerer needs to type the code instead of just copying it. Instead it would be much better to describe the problem in textual form, and focus on the problem that you did not understand. In addition, I assume that the code given above was taken from elsewhere, so it would be good style (and often even legally required) to reference its original source.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: First try to get the example running as is, and then put your data in `y_obs`.

Besides this, I suggest to use a minimum sum of squares algorithm first, before going to MCMC. StackOverflow contains several examples for this:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/67490904/3677576
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61623379/3677576

There are some more, just search for: [r] deSolve sir

For MCMC, several packages exist, e.g. **adaptMCMC** used in the code above. Another option would be package **FME**, because it describes model calibration and MCMC by example of a HIV model, that is quite similar to the SIR model shown above. Details are described in the paper of:

Soetaert et al. (2010) Inverse Modelling, Sensitivity and Monte Carlo Analysis in R Using Package FME. Journal of Statistical Software, 33(3) https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v033.i03.